# Overloading difficulty with an extended sprite class. How is this wrong?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overloading

So I've been working on a puzzle game using a sprite system I used fine previously and in my past projects have been fine when extending the class, however my code keeps throwing an error of

> error C2511:
>   'Door:: Door(float,float,float,float,float,float,int,CGame *)' :
>   overloaded member function not found in 'Door'

and I have no idea why as i've checked all the classes in my previous project and how they interface with the rest of the program and it's IDENTICAL but this new class is still erroring out. and the code in my main to create the object throws "no overloaded function in Door takes 8 arguments" out.

Door Class:

Door.h

```
#pragma once
#include "sprite.h"

class CGame;

class Door :
    public CSprite
{
public:
    Door(void);
    Door(float, float, float, float,float, float, float, int, CGame * p_Game);
    void Update(float dt);
    ~Door(void);

private:

};
```

Door.CPP

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Door.h"
#include "Game.h"

Door::Door(void)
{

}
        //So this is where i try to make door class extend sprite. but it keeps saying "overloaded member function not found in Door" 
        //and the other error is "doesnt take 8 args" and to top it off. It says unexpected end of file. 
        //Uncomment this block and the code in the door bit of the map gen to see what it is doing wrong

Door::Door(float _x, float _y, float _w, float _h, float _vX, float _vY, int _texID, CGame * p_Game) : CSprite(_x, _y, _w, _h, _vX, _vY, _texID, p_Game)
{
 m_iType = 4                //sets the type of sprite that this object is.
}

void Door::Update(float dt)
{
}
Door::~Door(void)
{
}
```

and this is the sprite class i am extending (just the relevant parts)

Sprite.h

```
#pragma once

class CGame;


class CSprite  
{
public:
    float m_fX; //the position of the centre of the sprite
    float m_fY;
    float m_fW; //width of the sprite in arbitrary units
    float m_fH; //height of the sprite in arbitrary units
    float m_fvX;
    float m_fvY;
    int m_iTextureID; //which of the preloaded textures to use

    float m_fR; //red component between 0 and 1
    float m_fG; //green component between 0 and 1
    float m_fB; //blue component between 0 and 1
    float m_fA; //alpha value 0-1
    int m_iType;
    CGame * m_pGame;

public:
    CSprite();
    CSprite(float x, float y, float w, float h,float vX,float vY, int textureID ,CGame * p_Game);
    bool bIsCollidingWith( CSprite * othersprite_);
    bool markedForDelete;
//This new constructor is added to the Csprite.h header file.
    float getX() { return m_fX; }
    float getY() { return m_fY; }
    virtual bool TagForDeletion();
    virtual int GetSpriteType();
    virtual ~CSprite();
    virtual void Render();
    virtual void Update(float dt);

};
```

Sprite.cpp

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <gl.h>
#include <glut.h>
#include <glaux.h>
#include "main.h"
#include "sprite.h"
#include "Game.h"
CSprite::CSprite( )
{
    m_fX=0.0f;
    m_fY=0.0f;
    m_fW=1.0f;
    m_fH=1.0f;
    m_fvX=0.0f;
    m_fvY=0.0f;
    markedForDelete=false;
    m_fR=m_fG=m_fB=m_fA=1.0;
    m_iTextureID=0;

}

CSprite::CSprite(float x_, float y_, float w_, float h_,float vX_,float vY_, int textureID_, CGame * p_Game)
{
    m_iType = 1;
    m_fX=x_;
    m_fY=y_;
    m_fW=w_;
    m_fH=h_;
    m_fvX=vX_;
    m_fvY=vY_;
    m_fR=m_fG=m_fB=m_fA=1.0;
    m_iTextureID=textureID_;
    m_pGame = p_Game;
    markedForDelete=false;
}

CSprite::~CSprite(void)
{
}
```

Implementation in the game class uses the parameters extended from Sprite to create the object

```
p_Door[m_iSpritesLoaded++]=new Door(uiRow,4.58 -uiCol,1,1,0,0,4,this);
```

Comment: Functions with 10 parameters are definitely a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: The compilation error is a code smell.

Comment: Indeed, better something like: `Sprite(const Rect& rect, const Vector2D& velocity, int textureId, Game* game)` where `rect` takes care of describing the position and size (could also be two vectors), etc.

Answer (score 1):

You miscounted your `float`s.

#### Declaration

```
Door(float, float, float, float,float, float, float, int, CGame * p_Game);
//     1      2      3      4     5      6      7
```

#### Definition

```
Door::Door(float _x, float _y, float _w, float _h, float _vX, float _vY, int _texID, CGame * p_Game)
//           1         2         3         4         5          6 
   : CSprite(_x, _y, _w, _h, _vX, _vY, _texID, p_Game)
```

#### Usage

```
p_Door[m_iSpritesLoaded++]=new Door(uiRow,4.58 -uiCol,1,1,0,0,4,this);
//                                    1     2         3 4 5 6
```

---

<sup>(Did you *really* need Stack Overflow for this?!)</sup>

Comment: Note that, as @FredOverflow says, this is a code smell -- the fact that you developed a bug in _counting function arguments_ is epic proof of that.

Comment: 4.58 -uiCol       <-     Note that there is no comma between these values since this calculation is applied to the single parameter

Comment: @grimpunch: Whoo! Well spotted. :) (Just the declaration is wrong, then.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `Door` constructor has one extra `float` parameter. The declaration has 7 `float`s whereas the definition in `Door.cpp` has 6.

Comment: If so, please accept the answer you feel was the most helpful so that the author gets credit.

Answer (score 0):

In Door.h the constructor has 9 arguments
Door(float, float, float, float,float, float, float, int, CGame * p_Game);
while in the Door.cpp the definition of the constructor has only 8 elements, that is one `float` is missing.

Solution:
add one argument to the definition of the constructor

`CSprite::CSprite(float x_, float y_, float w_, float h_,float vX_,float vY_, int textureID_, CGame * p_Game)`